Is it possible to have some cells in a table row to have vertical flow instead or horizontal using css?
I have a basic table:
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3, Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 3, Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Is it possible to make last row elements have vertical flow instead of horizontal?
Here's what I want to achieve:


First create individual tr for both td and then add colspan="2" to td. Below is working example.


<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1, Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 1, Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2, Cell 1</td>
    <td>Row 2, Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Row 3, Cell 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Row 3, Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>




Not sure if this answers the question. Your suggested solution modifies the document (to have four rows instead of three) rather than using style to achieve the goal.

@BrettDonald, yes, that's correct. The goal is to use css instead of modifying the document. At the moment, I'm getting data from backend and am rendering it inside the table. The last row is for description and because it has a lot of text, the value is on a separate line from key. Right now, I just have last row added manually, but I wonder if it's possible to just render through data object and display it inside table and then modify last row of table using css. I guess it can be achieved with css flex but I'd rather use table.

@in43sh I don't think you can achieve that with using table and css only. You can add logic for last element from backend so that they will be in two seperate tr and there is only one response on this question till now says that there might not be possible solution, Good Luck.
